# Use of MyApplication.context in my piece of code which i need to test using jUnit or Roboelectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I need to test a function which uses MyApplication.context. I cannot change the code of my function. I need to test this function with either jUnit or Roboelectric.

Let's say I need to test the bellow code.

```
 public Context getMyContext() {
    context = MyApplication.context;
    return context;
}
```

Above code is in my project which I cannot change.
How can I Assert whether the context is null or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in jUnit

`assertNotNull(yourObject.getMyContext());`

Comment: It gives null pointer exception at {context = MyApplication.context;}

Comment: If your context is null then it will throw null pointer exception

Comment: Agree, but each time it will give me null pointer even if my code is perfectly correct.

Comment: Are you running the test locally or on the emulator? If you are running it on the JVM then it will thrown an exception. In order to run tests related to Context , you should run them on the emulator and place them in "androidTest" package and not "test" package.Make sure you run them with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`.

Comment: Thanks that helped.

Comment: I have a question, what is the difference between Robolectric and @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)